# Global catch for BackgroundWorkers

Tags: c#, .net, exception, .net-4.5, backgroundworker

I have the following C# console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var handler = new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(ExceptionHandler);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += handler;

        try
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("About to fail");
                throw new ApplicationException("Bad Things");
            };
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException -= handler;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED!!!!  :(
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).Message);
    }
}
```

Basically it sets up a AppDomain exception handler, and then throws an exception on a background worker.

A lot of the questions on stack overflow about this seem to indicate that my method `ExceptionHandler` should be called.

But it is not.

**Is there a way to get notified of all exceptions in my application?**  Especially those that go unhanded from BackgroundWorkers?

NOTE: My real application is a huge WPF application.  This is just a scaled down scenario for my question.  (An interesting side note, in my application, I have one BackgrounWorker that does have its exceptions bubble up to global handler.  The rest don't.  But one of them does.  I can't figure out why....)

Comment: Try adding an event for Application.ThreadException too and seeing of it's ending up there.

Comment: Isn't the finally block going to potentially execute before the exception is thrown/bubbles up?